# Persistent job queue?

Tags: database, message-queue, priority-queue, task-queue

Internet says using database for queues is an anti-pattern, and you should use (RabbitMQ or Beanstalked or etc)

But I want all requests stored. So I can later lookup how long they took, any failed attempts or errors or notes logged, who requested it and with what metadata, what was the end result, etc.

It looks like all the queue libraries don't have this option. You can't persist the data to allow you to query it later.

I want what those queues do, but with a "persist to database" option. Does this not exist? How do people deal with this? Do you use a queue library and copy over all request information into your database when the request finishes?

(the language/database I'm using is anything, whatever works best for this)

Comment: Redis is brilliant for this - and fast.

Comment: @MarkSetchell redis doesn't do well with storing a ton of data (every single request made, not deleting old ones). Also you can't query redis well at all (show all requests made by user 1 in past month)

Comment: How much task throughput do you need?

Comment: @D-side I don't need a lot of throughput. My requests are lowish volume, but need high detail about what they were doing, error handling, notes, etc

Comment: Queue tables are not an anti pattern if you build them correctly. If you want to store work items they are a great solution. Your avatar is hilarious.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log requests, and meta-data about how long they took etc, then do so - log it to the database when you know the relevant results, and run your analytic queries as you would expect to.

The reason to not be using the database as a temporary store is that under high traffic, the searching for, and locking of unprocessed jobs, and then updating or deleting them when they are complete, can take a great deal of effort. That is especially true if don't remove jobs from the active table, and so have to search ever more completed jobs to find those that have yet to be done.

Comment: What if I need to show real-time progress of these requests to the user. Including progress bars and notes. You still think it makes sense to use a message queue and copy over information to my database instead of directly using my db for the queue?

Comment: That part is a job for Redis

Answer (score 0):

One can implement the task queue by themselves using a persistent backend (like database) to persist the tasks in queues. But the problem is, it may not scale well and also, it is always better to use a proven implementation instead of reinventing the wheel. These are tougher problems to solve and it is better to use the existent frameworks.

For instance, if you are implementing in Python, the typical choice is to use Celary with Redis/RabbitMQ backend.